# Which kind of error is generated by the following program

Tags: c, error-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *fun() 
{ 
    int j = 18; 
    return &j; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int *p = fun(); 
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

I am having confusion between compile time error and runtime error. Will the above code result in compile time error or runtime error. Anyone with clarity kindly explain major differences between various errors like compile time error, syntax error, semantic error, logical error, runtime error etc.

Comment: Compile it. Did it compile without displaying any errors or warnings? If no, then there were compile-time errors.

Comment: What is the error message? I see only potential runtime error because of UB (`j` out of scope).

Answer (score 0):

While your question lacks focus, there is one specific problem with it.

You have returned the address of a local variable. In `fun`, the variable `j` has an automatic lifetime limited to the function call. Returning a pointer to that variable invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is valid code, and will compile, but your compiler should warn you about it. Warnings typically hint at sources of potential run-time errors. *However* because the behavior is undefined, there may not actually be a runtime error.

Comment: can you elaborate more about undefined behaviour

Comment: The name's fairly self-explanatory, but for more details, I added a link to a relevant wikipedia article to my answer.